# IFFT using FFT by taking conjugate of the FFT result

Tags: math, signal-processing, fft

I am doing fixed point FFT on 8bit pic microcontrller using C language, i am able to get the FFT result from the sample i have taken but i am getting wrong output when i do the IFFT for the FFT result.

The flow of program i am doing is as follows

1. Doing FFT for 8 samples say example: Real value are (1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) and Imaginary values are (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
2. The output of the FFT is (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) and imaginary values are (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
3. Then taking the conjugate of FFT output
4. Doing FFT for the conjugated result
5. Again taking the conjugate of the second time FFT result
6. Finally dividing by 8 to get the original samples in time domain
   The output is Real value are (1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) and Imaginary values are (0,-0,-0,-0,-0,-0,-0,-0);

But if i apply the same for Real values (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) and imaginary values (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) i am getting wrong result such as real value after IFFT are (1,2,4,7,4,5,4,5) and Imaginary values are(-0,-3,-1,-0,1,0,0,2)

please help me what i am doing wrong...

Comment: Can you show example values for each step? Did you try a prototype that is not fixed point and not restricted to the microcontroller but following the same computation steps? Could you post that?

Comment: ya sir i have tried but i am not getting for that also... but the this logic is mentioned for IFFT

Comment: As I said below, the logic is (nearly) correct as IFFT(x)=conj(FFT(conj(x))/N, there is a second conjugation that should not matter when the output is real. Thus there has to be a problem with the implementation that can only be analyzed on the code, or at least with a trace of the computation.

Comment: Thank you for reply... I Have analyzed the code FFT its working Perfect but IFFT using above logic its not... Is this logic is proper??

Comment: Yes, the logic is correct. Please test the input sequences (1,0,0,...,0), (0,1,0,0,...,0),...,(0,0,0,...,0,1) and report on the results. Is the format/arrangement/layout of the complex numbers in input and output identical?

Comment: Hello Sir.. for the input sequence(1,0,0,0,0,...0) the FFT Real values are (1,1,1,1,1......1) and Imaginary vale are (0,0,0,0,0,0,0) and after  performing IFFT using above i am getting same result as input.

Comment: Please add further details by directly editing the question, there you have more space and better formatting. Just leave a comment that the question was updated.

Comment: Please do also report results with the unit vector, where the 1 is at position 2 and another with position 5. Add them as separate lists or table after the current list. The form of the results suggests, but not for sure, that the problem is with the ordering of the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FFT solves an interpolation problem, the IFFT the corresponding multi-point evaluation problem

The result of the FFT are coefficients of a polynomial p(z) where p(w<sup>k</sup>)=x<sub>k</sub>, w is the unit root associated with the dimension D of the FFT.

Denote with p<sub>s,k</sub>(z) the polynomial formed from the subsequence of coefficients of p(z) starting in k and spaced with index distance s.

If D=2N is even, the general idea to get from the values to the coefficients is to use w<sup>N</sup>=-1 and the decomposition

> p(z) = p<sub>2,0</sub>(z²) + z * p<sub>2,1</sub>(z²)

in the relations

> x<sub>k</sub> = p(w<sup>k</sup>)=p<sub>2,0</sub>(w<sup>2k</sup>) + w<sup>k</sup> * p<sub>2,1</sub>(w<sup>k</sup>)
>
> x<sub>N+k</sub> = p(w<sup>N+k</sup>) = p(-w<sup>k</sup>)
>
> = p<sub>2,0</sub>(w<sup>2k</sup>) - w<sup>k</sup> * p<sub>2,1</sub>(w<sup>2k</sup>)

to reduce the big interpolation problem into two subproblems of half the size,

> 2*p<sub>2,0</sub>(w<sup>2k</sup>) = x<sub>k</sub> + x<sub>N+k</sub>
>
> 2*p<sub>2,1</sub>(w<sup>2k</sup>) = w<sup>-k</sup> * (x<sub>k</sub> - x<sub>N+k</sub>)

In the next step,

- p<sub>2,0</sub> is reduced to p<sub>4,0</sub> and p<sub>4,2</sub>, and
- p<sub>2,1</sub> is reduced to p<sub>4,1</sub> and p<sub>4,3</sub>

etc.

---

For the sequence of 8 inputs, one gets in the first step w=(1+i)/sqrt(2) and w<sup>2</sup>=i

- x<sub>1,0</sub> = 2*p<sub>2,0</sub>( 1) = x<sub>0</sub> + x<sub>4</sub>
- x<sub>1,2</sub> = 2*p<sub>2,0</sub>( i) = x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>5</sub>
- x<sub>1,4</sub> = 2*p<sub>2,0</sub>(-1) = x<sub>2</sub> + x<sub>6</sub>
- x<sub>1,6</sub> = 2*p<sub>2,0</sub>(-i) = x<sub>3</sub> + x<sub>7</sub>

..

- x<sub>1,1</sub> = 2*p<sub>2,1</sub>( 1) = (x<sub>0</sub> - x<sub>4</sub>)*1
- x<sub>1,3</sub> = 2*p<sub>2,1</sub>( i) = (x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>5</sub>)*(1-i)/sqrt(2)
- x<sub>1,5</sub> = 2*p<sub>2,1</sub>(-1) = (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>6</sub>)*(-i)
- x<sub>1,7</sub> = 2*p<sub>2,1</sub>(-i) = (x<sub>3</sub> - x<sub>7</sub>)*(-1-i)/sqrt(2)

In the next step, one gets w=i and w<sup>2</sup>=-1

- x<sub>2,0</sub> = 4*p<sub>4,0</sub>( 1) = x<sub>1,0</sub> + x<sub>1,4</sub>
- x<sub>2,4</sub> = 4*p<sub>4,0</sub>(-1) = x<sub>1,2</sub> + x<sub>1,6</sub>

..

- x<sub>2,2</sub> = 4*p<sub>4,2</sub>( 1)= (x<sub>1,0</sub> - x<sub>1,4</sub>)*1
- x<sub>2,6</sub> = 4*p<sub>4,2</sub>(-1)= (x<sub>1,2</sub> - x<sub>1,6</sub>) * (-i)

--

- x<sub>2,1</sub> = 4*p<sub>4,1</sub>( 1) = x<sub>1,1</sub> + x<sub>1,5</sub>
- x<sub>2,5</sub> = 4*p<sub>4,1</sub>(-1) = x<sub>1,3</sub> + x<sub>1,7</sub>

..

- x<sub>2,3</sub> = 4*p<sub>4,3</sub>( 1)= (x<sub>1,1</sub> - x<sub>1,5</sub>)*1
- x<sub>2,7</sub> = 4*p<sub>4,3</sub>(-1)= (x<sub>1,3</sub> - x<sub>1,7</sub>) * (-i)

and finally the FFT coefficients X<sub>k</sub>=x<sub>3,k</sub> using w=-1 and w²=1

- X<sub>0</sub> = 8*p<sub>8,0</sub>( 1) = x<sub>2,0</sub> + x<sub>2,4</sub>
- X<sub>4</sub> = 8*p<sub>8,4</sub>( 1) = (x<sub>2,0</sub> - x<sub>2,4</sub>)*(-1)

--

- X<sub>2</sub> = 8*p<sub>8,2</sub>( 1) = x<sub>2,2</sub> + x<sub>2,6</sub>
- X<sub>6</sub> = 8*p<sub>8,6</sub>( 1) = (x<sub>2,2</sub> - x<sub>2,6</sub>)*(-1)

--

- X<sub>1</sub> = 8*p<sub>8,1</sub>( 1) = x<sub>2,1</sub> + x<sub>2,5</sub>
- X<sub>5</sub> = 8*p<sub>8,5</sub>( 1) = (x<sub>2,1</sub> - x<sub>2,5</sub>)*(-1)

--

- X<sub>3</sub> = 8*p<sub>8,3</sub>( 1) = x<sub>2,3</sub> + x<sub>2,7</sub>
- X<sub>7</sub> = 8*p<sub>8,7</sub>( 1) = (x<sub>2,3</sub> - x<sub>2,7</sub>)*(-1)

---

Please check that these steps are reflected in your code, especially, that the square root of 2 occurs at the necessary places. It is highly unlikely that the output of random integer inputs is again strictly integer.

Answer (score 0):

In your description there, at no point do you take an inverse DFT.

Think about what is going on, lets say you have the the DFT result as X, taking X*X is going to give you the power spectrum, not an inverse DFT. Then preforming an DFT on this will not give you a time domain, it will give you nonsense.

you need to find the inverse DFT function in the library you are using.

Comment: Your remark is correct in general, but wrong in the case of the FFT. There you have IFFT(x)=conj(FFT(conj(x))/N, so in principle, this algorithm should work.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? Just looking at the integral form of the Fourier transform that doesn't match up. Also units don't work out. You have units of time equals inverse time

Comment: We are dealing with the DFT here, no integrals, just sums. Units do not change.

Comment: A DFT is a special case of the integral, and a Fourier transform does change the units. You take something from a time space to a frequency space, you change units.

Comment: Where exaktly in X[k]=sum(m=0 to N-1) exp(-2*pi*i*k*m/N)*x[m] does the change in units happen?

Comment: Its in the sum of time units. Its more obvious in the integral form when you have the factor of dt. That still has units. An sum is just an integral of desecrate quantities, just some of the notations are different.

Comment: Of course, in passing to the integral form one divides up the factor of 1/N into the dx and df increments. I put this kind of relationship in writing here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/633725/115115. Nevertheless, the DFT just multiplies the samples with phase factors and sums them up, no change of unit happens, it's all in the interpretation of the result.

Comment: Mr LutzL is right i am trying to do IFFT(x)=conj(FFT(conj(X))/N. but the result what i am getting is wrong